# Weird outline on input:focus

Tags: html, css, input, focus

I'm using materializecss for my project but I have a problem.
I have disabled the outline of the inputs but the inputs still showing up a weird outline on focus.

[image: This is the problem]

This is the css for the inputs

```
.inputs input[type=text]:focus {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF!important;
  background-color: #FAFAFA!important;
  box-shadow: none!important;
  outline:none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a question here, but I am assuming you want to get rid of the outline altogether?

If you provide more details I'll be able to give more accurate answer, but first thing that comes to mind from looking at provided gif is that maybe that outline comes from an :active state.

You can remove outline for both states on the bare element and see if that has some impact:

```
input:focus, 
input:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

If this didn't solve your problem, please give some more input (pun intended :)) and we'll figure it out.

Best, 
N.

P.S. Upon further inspection, it seems to me that when you click, the border is set. That's also why your input fields move a little bit (can you see that)? Please update your code. This should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely the :active pseudo class as it seems like the border is changing when you click.

Try making a rule that changes both the focus and active pseudo classes.

```
.inputs input[type=text]:active,
.inputs input[type=text]:focus {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF!important;
  background-color: #FAFAFA!important;
  box-shadow: none!important;
  outline:none!important;
}
```